# SQL query total vs a single value

Tags: mysql, sql

I've been working on a query with a peer and it has been turning back some unusual numbers. The query is a productivity report. I'm trying to total the all of the billable units for a specific end user, compare that total to single expected value, and then calculate the difference between those 2 numbers within a 1 week period of time. Here is what we have come up with so far:

```
SELECT
 Employees.emp_id,
 Employees.last_name+', '+Employees.first_name as staff_name,
 SUM(VisitQuery.billed_value)/60 AS billed_value,
 SUM(StandardQuery.num8) as expected_value
FROM
 Employees
INNER JOIN
(
  SELECT
   ClientVisit.duration AS billed_value,
   ClientVisit.emp_id,
   ClientVisit.client_id
  FROM
   ClientVisit
  WHERE
   ClientVisit.non_billable = 0 AND
   ClientVisit.rev_timeout >= @param1 AND
   ClientVisit.rev_timeout <= @param2
) VisitQuery
ON VisitQuery.emp_id = Employees.emp_id
INNER JOIN
(
 SELECT DISTINCT
  CaseloadQuery.emp_id,
  ClientsExt.num8
 FROM
 (
  SELECT
   ClientVisit.duration AS billed_value,
   ClientVisit.emp_id,
   ClientVisit.client_id
  FROM
   ClientVisit
  WHERE
   ClientVisit.non_billable = 0 AND
   ClientVisit.rev_timeout >= @param1 AND
   ClientVisit.rev_timeout <= @param2
 ) CaseloadQuery
 INNER JOIN ClientsExt
 ON CaseloadQuery.client_id = ClientsExt.client_id
) StandardQuery
ON Employees.emp_id = StandardQuery.emp_id
GROUP BY
 Employees.emp_id,
 Employees.last_name+', '+Employees.first_name`enter code here`
```

The return comes out looking like this:

```
emp_id      staff_name      billed_value    expected_value
X           X               74              231
XX          XX              108             279
XXX         XXX             19              72
```

Does anyone have any thoughts? The expected value should really not be any higher that 40 hours for the week.

Comment: Could You provide class/domain diagram? it would be really helpful, cheers

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm relatively new to SQL so I'm not exactly sure what you are asking me for.

Comment: In the table `ClientVisit`, can the same employee (`emp_id`) has multiple rows that lead to multiple values of `client_id`?

Answer (score 0):

In the table `ClientVisit`, can the same employee (`emp_id`) has multiple rows that lead to multiple values of client_id?  If the answer is yes, then I think you should also do a `GROUP BY` on `client_id`

Below I tried rewriting your query (pay attention to the lines marked with "add" and "delete").

**Disclaimer**: I don't have your actual DB tables to test my query, so it may have syntax and semantic bugs

```
SELECT
    Employees.emp_id,
    StandardQuery.client_id,                                        -- add 
    Employees.last_name+', '+Employees.first_name as staff_name,
    SUM(VisitQuery.billed_value)/60 AS billed_value,
    SUM(StandardQuery.num8) as expected_value
FROM
    Employees
    INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT
                ClientVisit.duration AS billed_value,
                ClientVisit.emp_id,
                ClientVisit.client_id
            FROM
                ClientVisit
            WHERE
                ClientVisit.non_billable = 0 AND
                ClientVisit.rev_timeout >= @param1 AND
                ClientVisit.rev_timeout <= @param2
        ) VisitQuery 
        ON VisitQuery.emp_id = Employees.emp_id
    INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT DISTINCT
                CaseloadQuery.emp_id,
                ClientsExt.num8,
                ClientsExt.client_id                                -- add
            FROM
                (
                    SELECT
                        -- ClientVisit.duration AS billed_value,    -- delete
                        ClientVisit.emp_id,
                        ClientVisit.client_id
                    FROM
                        ClientVisit
                    WHERE
                        ClientVisit.non_billable = 0 AND
                        ClientVisit.rev_timeout >= @param1 AND
                        ClientVisit.rev_timeout <= @param2
                )CaseloadQuery
                INNER JOIN ClientsExt 
                    ON CaseloadQuery.client_id = ClientsExt.client_id
        )StandardQuery 
            ON Employees.emp_id = StandardQuery.emp_id
GROUP BY
    Employees.emp_id, 
    -- Employees.last_name+', '+Employees.first_name                -- delete
    StandardQuery.client_id                                         -- add
```